# How can I remove the head of a main function?

Tags: c, parameters, program-entry-point, argv, argc

I am trying to move some code from a separate binary and have it inside my main program. Unfortunately I can't mimic the initialization variables for the main function.

How can I create `argc` and `argv` by hand? Can someone give me some example assignments.

since it looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

I figured I could assign them like this:

```
int argc=1;
char *argv[0]="Example";
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how this might be done?

Comment: What you say should work. Can you post some code of what are you actually doing?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example? How did you "move" the function?

Comment: you need to allocate space for your argv-array, one pointer worth of space, so that should be `char *argv[1] = {"Example"};`

Comment: @roe: That's mostly correct, but to be *completely* correct, he really needs `argv[argc]` to be a null pointer, so it ought to be `char *argv [2] = { "Example", NULL };`

Comment: The arguments should also be modifiable but string literals aren't.

Comment: @Dan: why is that though? argc tells you how many entries there are

Comment: @roe: Yes, it's redundant, but the C standard says that `argv[argc]` must be a null pointer. It's best to supply it, even though it's redundant, because a conforming `main` function might expect to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int argc = 3;
char *argv[4];
argv[0] = "fake /path/to/my/program";
argv[1] = "fake arg 1";
argv[2] = "fake arg 2";
argv[3] = NULL;
fakemain(argc, argv);
```

Comment: .. or just `char *argv[4] = {"fake /path/to/my/program", "fake arg 1", "fake arg 2", NULL}` to save you some real estate.

Answer (score 1):

The last element of the `argv[]` array is actually `argv[argc]` which is a `NULL` pointer.

Some example code:

```
char *argv[] = { "first", "second", NULL }; 
int argc = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(*argv) - 1;
```